# Trouble installing Teamspeak3 server on VPS (Says server is running but can't connect)

Tags: linux, centos, teamspeak

I'm trying to install teamspeak3 server on my VPS (CentOS 7). Everything seems to be installed correctly, it says the server is running when I try to run the startscript again, however I can't connect to the IP that I find in ifconfig. Anyone who could help me out here?

Comment: Are you connecting from your external IP? Are your ports forwarded correctly?

Comment: @EricF i am connecting from my external IP, yes. About the ports, I followed a guide and it says little to nothing about port forwarding. I'm still pretty new to linux too so honestly I wouldn't know. Thank you for the reply

Comment: That is my guess as to why it is not working then. Your router is blocking the incoming traffic.  Which brand router do you have?

Comment: Also port forwarding has nothing to do with linux. It all happens in your router settings. If you tell me your router model I can help tell you how to do this

Comment: @EricF  My home router? It shouldn't be a problem with my home router because I can connect to other teamspeak servers on the same port just fine. It's not a brand, it's a router I got from my ISP, I can do port forwarding manually through their website

Comment: Connecting to other servers has nothing to do with it. When connecting to other servers you don't need ports open. Whenever expecting others (including yourself) to connect to your own IP address you need to forward that data past your firewall. You will have to look up the port that TS uses and forward that to your own internal IP address.

Comment: @EricF The default port that teamspeak uses is 9987, however the linux server is not on my network. It's on a VPS that I rent. How would I go about port forwarding on a network I don't have access to?

Comment: Ask the owner of that server to ensure that port 9987 is open then

Comment: @EricF I'll check with the helpdesk. Thank you

Comment: @EricF I was just checking things out some more. Could it be related to iptables?

Comment: @EricF I figured it out. iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9987 -j ACCEPT did the trick

Comment: Glad I could help then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to change my firewall (iptables) to allow input from the port.

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 9987 -j ACCEPT
```